# GMSMarker nos display GroundAnchor iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, maps, google-maps-markers

I'm doing with GMSMaker, my maker's icon is fine, but i can't set `groundAnchor`, it not display at all, and i don't know why ?? 
All is fine, just groundAnchor
Can somebody hepl me ?

```
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
                let icon = UIImage(named: "m\(index+1).png")
                let scaled = self.scaleImage(icon!, scale: 0.5)
                marker.title = placeType.name
                marker.icon = scaled
                marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop
                marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 1)
                marker.map = self.mMapView
```

Answer (score 2):

The groundAnchor is the offset relative to center of icon in `GSMarker` where `CGPoint(0.5,0.5)` is the default value correspond to the center of `GSMarker`, so in your example your are adjusting the offset to center of `width` and the full `height`

### Google Maps SDK for iOS documentation

> The ground anchor specifies the point in the icon image that is
>   anchored to the marker's position on the Earth's surface. This point
>   is specified within the continuous space [0.0, 1.0] x [0.0, 1.0],
>   where (0,0) is the top-left corner of the image, and (1,1) is the
>   bottom-right corner.

This property don't show anything additionally to your `GSMarker`

I hope this helps you

Comment: so what should i set in this case @Reinier

Comment: can you post a picture with your marker on the map and the position desired?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Here is it]

The groundAnchor didn't show up at all

Comment: @Reinier Melian here is it